# Geopolitical ramifications of a faked Apollo 11 Moon landing being exposed?

Tags: alternate-history, moons, science-in-society, geopolitics, conspiracy

Imagine it's an alternate July 20th, 1969. The American people and anybody with a television set watch as Neil Armstrong and Buzz Aldrin step out of the Apollo Lunar Module Eagle and become the first humans to walk on the Moon's surface. Over half a billion people across the world watch this broadcast, and everyone hails it as the greatest human achievement of the 20th century...until multiple members of NASA personnel begin coming forward, claiming that the Apollo 11 crew never really left Earth. Months of government denial, scandals, dismissals, protests, and leaked documents/photos eventually lead to the American people and everyone on Earth finally learning the truth in 1970: the Apollo landing was covertly faked on a government soundstage.

**If this ever did happen, what would be a plausible geopolitical ramification of the moon landing being exposed as a fake ?**

My question isn't about HOW the Moon landing could've been faked, but what political and scientific backlashes the United States government would face from *trying* to fake the landing.

Comment: Neat idea, but I think this question is way too broad: "What would be the **full ramifications**?" You will need to narrow it down. It's also missing some important info: in this alternate universe, exactly how much of the space race was real and how much was faked? And, what about non-US space efforts, e.g. was Sputnik real?

Comment: Agree with @Tom and the other huge bit of missing background is where the money went.  One of the big criticisms of the moon landing conspiracy theory is that with the technology limits back then it would have cost more to convincingly fake the landing than to actually do it.  If it was a fake then actions regarding the money recipients would be key but the OP does not specify who that is.

Comment: The other NASA missions except up to the Apollo 11 landing were real, as well as the USSR's other space exploration achievements. And I've decided to narrow it down to just the scientific and geopolitical consequences that the United States would face for actually trying to fake the Moon mission.

Comment: One could make this argument if you were a skeptical character in this universe: if NASA and the government managed to fake #11, who's to say they also didn't do the same for the other Apollo missions?

Comment: I'm with @VogonPoet on this. It is crucial to describe *how* the landing wes faked. For example, Apollo 11 placed a [retroreflector on the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Laser_Ranging_experiment), which is used for measuring the distance to Moon very precisely. If the Apollo 11 landing was faked, how did this mirror get there? And where did the lunar rocks come from? The *how* is both important and quite interesting.

Comment: (1/2) The biggest issue with any sort of moon-landing fakery is that you need to explain why the Soviets didn't debunk it. You can bet that during the Moon landing, the Soviet space program had all their radio telescopes and other resources independently tracking the mission as closely as possible and likely even had intelligence assets within NASA following along with Apollo's progress. If there had been even a *thought* of faking the moon landing, the Soviets would've been all over that and denounced the USA as charlatans on the international stage, but they didn't.

Comment: Same result as the Gulf of Tonkin false flag or WMD in Iraq being exposed as a lie. Nothing. The public has a very short attention span and will move on after a week.

Comment: (2/2) Since any "reveal" would likely come from the Soviets, the USA would likely dismiss any and all evidence as red propaganda, and simply deny, deny, deny forever. NASA personnel who "come forward" would simply be branded as Soviet agents and as McCarthyism and "red scare" was still somewhat in-vogue, the "Soviet Assets" would simply be disappeared and sent to concentration camps or whatever.

Comment: I've put a small edit in title and question.. when it focuses on "a geopolitical ramification" the question is less broad and less story based? vtr @NathanHop if you don't like my edit, undo it ;)

Comment: Sorry this edit only asks for a smaller story, and we don’t know what event happened. At first NASA *did* fake the landing on a soundstage, but at the end they *tried to* fake it. In either case, you have to explain in your story: *what did NASA actually do?* “Faking to be a cop” isn’t an act, but “dressing up in a police officer uniform and stealing a cop car” is a story. Explain what “fake” means please (from your story). Those acts decide how the world responds.

Comment: @VogonPoet I tried to move this question a bit keeping o.m.'s answer in.. to be independent of that event which caused the exposure. Remove focus from the story details and shift to geopolitical ramifications, helicopter view. These are world topics, rather than story things. Alternate history and politics are both tagged by the opener, so why not ?

Comment: @goodies The scope is too broad, we don’t know how far he needs this carried. We can tell you what would happen in August 1969. The Soviet Union wins the space race. But where does the question end? 2022? Do we predict the loss of the other 6 Apollo lander missions? Did Apollo 12 also get faked? There just isn’t enough story to build a geopolitical world objectively.

Comment: @VogonPoet building anything political is never "objective". There could be a most plausible solution, a best answer.. and there are votes and comments. Now, there is no answer option at all. I have put my edit to focus this on politics, because that  can resolve the story-based issue. What are the repercussions for NOW, the current time. There was a good answer (om) and It would be an interesting worldbuilding question in the "Alternate History" section. Ideas only, no objective chronicles can be made and no objective science can be applied. Alternate history has nothing to do with science.

Comment: I doubt in the modern era much would happen. A few people would roll their eyes maybe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **An international loss of faith in the US**
  Some people (who are inclined to support the US anyway) might have some admiration in this *audacious psy-op* to help win the Cold War. More would seize on it to dismiss other, unrelated statements by the US. Expect more [Whataboutism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whataboutism) in international discourse. But then the [Weapons of Mass Distraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq_and_weapons_of_mass_destruction) didn't totally discredit the US, and they were used to justify an invasion.
- **A domestic increase in conspiracy theorists**
  There have always been crackpots. A couple of decades ago, they might have handed out [mimeographed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimeograph) or typed leaflets with bad typesetting and an excessive number of exclamation marks. Today, they have YouTube or Telegram channels. They latch onto not proven issues regarding the [Kennedy assassination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_John_F._Kennedy), and complete nonsense about certain fast food restaurants.
  Having the mainstream believe in **one** conspiracy theory will prompt more people to believe in **other** conspiracy theories.
- **A convenient lever for science denial**
  There are groups who publicly deny [climate change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_change_denial), [tobacco lethality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobacco_Master_Settlement_Agreement), or the [effectiveness of vaccination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccine_hesitancy). One might think that one more topic does not matter, but that again brings up Whataboutism. "If they lied about the Moon, you can go on driving gas-guzzling SUVs."

Comment: Considering the time period, it is more believable the conspiracy nutjobs are the ones who claim smoking is bad for you and not the other way around.

Comment: @Daron, my point is that nutcases thrive on a diet of lies, what will happen when they get some *real* facts to go along with them?

Comment: But real facts are commonplace

Comment: +1 interesting observations about the consequences of finding out some *major event* did not actually happen (any event). The moon landing specifically would discredit all space travel: you can tell your audience Hubble's images are faked, the shuttle never exploded, there are no rovers on Mars and you can't reach the moon, because  the Earth is flat... the moon is just a lamp on a rail hanging from the ceiling, light years away from us. The moon is fake.

Comment: @Goodies, not just the moon, but **any** result a layperson cannot reproduce. Climate change? Just weather! Tobacco? I know a smoker who got 100 years old!

Comment: The reality is that 'acceptance of science' is, ironically, a faith position for most people; it's a belief that the scientific authorities are telling the truth.  Remove trust, and the basis for that faith collapses. The moon landing being shown to be fake would be catastrophic. Depending on who organised it, Nixon doesn't bother with Watergate because he knows he's going to win,  romps in with his 49 state victory and serves a full second term. Or, he resigns in disgrace earlier, leading to President Spiro Agnew and goodness knows what happens.